# EXCEL VBA : Run-Time error '9': Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA Excel. I am trying to compare cells from two different sheets and if they are same, I need to perform the calculation as shown below.

The problem is, when I run I get a `Run-Time error '9': Subscript out of range` on the following line `Set rng1 = Sheets(“Monday”).Range("K" & i)`

```
Sub updateWOhrs()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

For i = 6 To 15

    For j = 1 To 400
    Set rng1 = Sheets(“Monday”).Range("K" & i)
    Set rng2 = Sheets(“LINKED”).Range("C" & j)

        If rng1.Value = rng2.Value Then
            Sheets(“LINKED”).Cells(j, 4) = Sheets(“LINKED”).Cells(j, 4) + Sheets(“Monday”).Cells(i, 19)
        End If


    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: When you get the error - goto the immediate window and what happens when you type ?Sheets(“Monday”).name does that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace “Monday” with "Monday" and “LINKED” with "LINKED" (notice the different type of quotation mark " instead of “).